# windows django server

Tags: windows, django, comparison, apache, httpserver

I have inherited a Windows Server and I have to deploy a django app on it.

Have anyone tried to benchmark http servers with django support on this platform?
Which one is fastest?

Use-case of my application would be:

- not so much writes to db
- heavy usage of admin panel
- display tons of results

Comment: Please take a look at this article [Running Django on Windows (with performance tests)](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at either [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)? They both deliver Apache/MySQL/PHP-and-Perl on a Windows platform. But you need more because neither includes Python. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000444/run-django-with-xampp-on-windows) for how to proceed from there. Note, you may encounter problems. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164921/running-python-code-on-xampp-on-windows-platform) for an example.

Ps. Personally, I would just get a an account that supports Django (e.g. webfaction.com) and not screw around with this.

Comment: not possible, I have to deploy a django CRM application which I have been  developing since 2009, and it has to work intranet only! I did deployed it with Apache2 and I am wondering if there is something better

Comment: @haras.pl: You don't say what is wrong with Apache, so it's hard to say what is better. If you are trying to survive on a small/slow machine, you might look at nginx - a super lightweight server. Here's an article on getting it to work on Windows. http://www.kevinworthington.com/nginx-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I run a Django site on Windows using Apache. I've posted a write up about [some of the hurdles that you're going to face](http://manfre.net/article/2108/running-python-and-apache-on-windows).

Comment: That link is broken